# Access child components ref inside parent component in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

I am having a parent and child component the looks like this

```
export function Parent(){
  function handleClick(){
     // Here I need to access Child components ref, that may be taken to this function as a parameter
  }

  return(
    <>
      <h1> Parent component here </h1>
      <Child/>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Get Ref</button> 
    </>
  )
}


export function Child(){
  const childRef = useRef("test")
  return(
    <h1> Child Component</h1>
  )
}
```

How do I get the ref that is defined inside the child component to be accessed inside the parent based on the button click in the parent component?

Comment: Set the useRef hook in your parent component in the <Child> tag

Answer (score 3):

You can use [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) to get a hold of the child ref in your parent component.

```
export function Parent(){
  const childRef = useRef();

  function handleClick(){
     console.log(childRef.current);
  }

  return(
    <>
      <h1> Parent component here </h1>
      <Child ref={childRef} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Get Ref</button> 
    </>
  )
}


export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return(
    <h1 ref={ref}>Child Component</h1>
  )
});
```

Alternatively, if you don't like to use `React.forwardRef`, you can also just pass the ref as prop. But you can't name it `ref` in this case.

```
export function Parent(){
  const childRef = useRef();

  function handleClick(){
     console.log(childRef.current);
  }

  return(
    <>
      <h1> Parent component here </h1>
      <Child innerRef={childRef} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Get Ref</button> 
    </>
  )
}


export default function Child({ innerRef }) {
  return(
    <h1 ref={innerRef}>Child Component</h1>
  )
});
```

Comment: I want the childs ref value to be used in parent. I dont want to create a ref in parent . I just need to access

Comment: This is exactly how you would achieve that. You don't pass the ref Object from a child to parent, but you bind it to an existing ref Object defined in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try that. I passed function as props to child and set ref there when child rendered;

```
export function Parent(){
  function handleClick(value){
     var childRef = value;
  }

  return(
    <>
      <h1> Parent component here </h1>
      <Child handleClick={handleClick}/>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Get Ref</button> 
    </>
  )
}


export function Child({handleClick}){
  const childRef = useRef("test")
  handleClick(childRef)
  return(
    <h1> Child Component</h1>
  )
}
```